# How to fix the issue with <s:if> tag whcih is not identifying boolean value correctly

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am working on an issue where feedback for user rating is recorded. I am getting values from backend in a list and displaying radio buttons based on the values iterated from that list. I see that  is not checking the boolean value correctly

I have tried adding  for the boolean value and changed the way variable is being tested inside . Nothing worked out

```
<s:iterator value="selectedList" status="choice">
    <td>
    <s:if test="#choice">
      <span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -40px;">
                                         <p class="styled">Selected</p>
      </span>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
      <span class="radio"><p class="styled">Not Selected</p></span>

    </s:else>
    </td>
</s:iterator>
```

I expect the radio button to be selected if choice is true. Actual result is all radio buttons are selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working by below way -

```
<s:iterator value="selectedList" status="choice">
    <s:set var="choiceStr"><s:property /></s:set>
        <td>
            <s:if test="#choiceStr == 'true'">
                <span class="radio" style="background-position: 0px -40px;">
                    <p class="styled">Selected</p>
                </span>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <span class="radio"><p class="styled">Not Selected</p></span>
            </s:else>
        </td>
</s:iterator>
```